# GD already installed but createimagefrompng not working on Mac

Tags: php, macos

Currently on OSX Yosemite

I'm trying to do

```
imagecreatefrompng($originalFile);
```

But got:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagecreatefrompng()
```

So I did a little search and found that I need to install the GD Library, which I did,

```
$ brew install gd
```

And i Got:

```
Warning: gd-2.1.0_2 already installed
```

So I searched a little more, and uncommented in my php.ini and restarted Apache

```
extension=php_gd2.dll
```

Still not working.

So from here I'm lost, any pointers or suggestions?

EDIT:

[image: GD in php ini]

I belive I have related problem as [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26443242/after-upgrade-php-no-longer-supports-png-operations)

Comment: As you may see on your screenshot this version of `GD` lacks support for `PNG`. Rebuild it or install another version.

Answer (score 0):

Can you output your `phpinfo();` and check that the library is loaded correctly. Undefined function would suggest that it isn't. Check you are editing the correct php.ini file.

Comment: Did you try any of the answers in your link? It seems OSX ships with a version that doesnt fully support it so you need reinstall it manually either by the sh script provided or by brew?

Comment: I tried the accepted answer in the link I provided and it worked for me, but if I need to do it again in the future I would probably choose the other option with brew. See step by step instruction provided by Jpsy http://stackoverflow.com/a/26505558/430742