# Editing images using PHP on Mac OS Yosemite

Tags: php, macos, osx-yosemite

Apple has long bundled an instance of PHP as part of the default install. However since Mac OS 10.10 Yosemite they have dropped PNG support from GD.

What would currently be the most efficient way of substituting the functionality? I can't go around to everyone's computer and manually replace the php binary with a version from homebrew as commonly suggested, and my next favourite tool (imagemagick) I could use to do a quick file format conversion doesn't ship with Mac OS either.

Since I am fortunately in charge of the code, what are the alternatives/workarounds to load a PNG file into the default PHP install? Preferably it should not require any Mac OS specifics as the same code has to work on a few linux machines as well.

Comment: That's a very odd omission on Apple's part (so much so I'd suspect it was a mistake that'll be corrected in the next version). I suspect any workaround you come up with will be more complex, time consuming, and less reliable than updating PHP or installing imagemagick for everyone.

Comment: Practically, updating the code where it's already centralized will be less time consuming than pinging a ton of users (read: illiterate users) with additional instructions to install homebrew, xcode, and php.

Comment: Why are illiterate users working directly with a local install of PHP?

Comment: For the full backstory: they don't actually interact with it directly. There's a bunch of platform-specific wrapping code that calls the PHP code under the hood. Initially PHP was chosen because it actually allowed to share core functionality between various platforms as well as making it available behind a webserver, and it comes bundled with Mac OS by default.
And of course, I already filed a bug report, but I don't generally trust Apple although I do hope I don't end up keeping any workaround ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a one line solution here to run in a console:

`curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.6`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26559567/265636