# Drupal resizes uploaded JPG but not PNG

Tags: php, drupal-7

I have a strange behavior with Drupal. When I load a PNG in a image field it does upload the image but does not resize it.
The strange thing is that it works well with JPG.

I did :
    `chmod 777 files/`
and

```
chmod 775 files/
```

but did not change anything.

I am under :
OSX Yosemite 10.10.1, PHP 5.5.18 and apache 2.4.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once upgraded to Yosemite, PHP don't handle anymore PNG via GD.
So we have to install a new version of php with homebrew like explain here :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26505558/3656447