# can't create a Laravel project because mcrypt extension is missing

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, osx-yosemite, mcrypt

OK, I have seen many posts about this, and I have spent the entire day working through them to solve this issue, with no success.

I am trying to create a Laravel project. I am using a Mac (Yosemite), which is running PHP 5.5.14. There is also an older version of PHP on the machine. When I try to create a project from the command line using "laravel new *projectname*", no errors are reported, but the command just creates an empty folder named with the project name. I get the "Crafting application..." and "Application ready! Build something amazing" messages but, again, only an empty folder.

If I try to use this command:
 composer create-project laravel/laravel *projectname*

I get this:

Installing laravel/laravel (v5.0.16)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.0.16)
    Downloading: 100%

Created project in *projectname*
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - Installation request for laravel/framework v5.0.16 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.0.16].
    - laravel/framework v5.0.16 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.

In the terminal, if I enter this:
which php
I get: /usr/bin/php
/usr/bin/php -v
I get: 
PHP 5.5.14 (cli) (built: Sep  9 2014 19:09:25) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans

I used homebrew to install autoconf and mcrypt with this command:
brew install autoconf mcrypt

If I run that command again, I get:
Warning: autoconf-2.69 already installed
Warning: mcrypt-2.6.8 already installed

Since I kept getting the error, I assumed it was installed in the wrong place so, I compiled and installed mcrypt myself using these instructions:
[Install mcrypt php extension][1]. I used PHP version 5.5.14 during the install. Mcrypt was installed in this directory: /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/

I have restarted Apache. I have checked my .bash_profile to make sure /usr/bin is in my Path.

If I create a page with phpinfo() and view it in my browser, I see that mcrypt is listed in the "Module Authors" section of the page. It just lists the names of the people who created the module.

I am stumped. I look forward to any suggestions that people might offer (I really don't want to install a virtual box, or anything like that. Surely, I can get this module installed in the right place!)

Thanks very much!

Comment: Are you loading the extension in your ini config (something like `extension=mcrypt.so`)?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added "extension=mcrypt.so" to my php.ini file, and I restarted apache but, no luck. Still the same results when I try to create the laravel project using the composer command I listed above.

Comment: run `which mcrypt` to determine it's location and then add that to your path `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`.

Comment: I got it! When I added it to my php.ini file, I didn't do it correctly (I'm tired)! But, I fixed my mistake in the php.ini, and that has it working! Thank you so much! I don't remember seeing the addition to php.ini in any of the instructions I was working from...I will go back and check. I don't see how I could have missed that. Thanks again! What a relief to have this solved.

Comment: This answer worked for me: 
`sudo php5enmod mcrypt`
`sudo service apache2 restart`

http://askubuntu.com/questions/460837/mcrypt-extension-is-missing-in-14-04-server-for-mysql

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes, this is a valid, good question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Yosemite php-gd + mcrypt installation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26493762/yosemite-php-gd-mcrypt-installation)

Answer (score 13):

I got this exact same problem too.
You have to find `php.ini` for php cli and add `extension=mcrypt.so`

My system is running LAMPP server with preinstalled PHP. So, here's what I do:

**Install mcrypt extension**

I tried both:

```
sudo apt-get install mcrypt
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
```

**Configure php.ini for CLI**

Then, edit php.ini located in `/opt/lampp/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` add `extension=mcrypt.so` on **Dynamic Extension** section (anywhere is fine I think). Don't forget to restart your server.

**Try using composer to install laravel**

Now, you can run whatever method you want to install laravel. I download Laravel 5 manually, unzip, then install using `composer install` command. I think your command `composer create-project laravel/laravel projectname` would've run smoothly too.

References:
[here](http://laravel.io/forum/05-30-2014-mcrypt-php-extension-required)

Comment: Worked Perfectly on a ubuntu system

Comment: Great solution.

Answer (score 5):

**mac users** install brew  and then enter

```
brew install php56-mcrypt
```

in terminal

**EDIT**

if you get any error using above line then try this command

```
brew install homebrew/php/php56-mcrypt
```

Comment: Error: No available formula for php56-mcrypt

Answer (score 2):

Please following the step :

1. `cd /etc/php5/cli/conf.d`
2. `ln -s ../../mods-available/mcrypt.ini 20-mcrypt.ini`

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For MAC users,

> brew install homebrew/php/php56-mcrypt