# PHP changes not showing on local

Tags: php, mamp, osx-yosemite

I am using OSX Yosemite and I have installed MAMP. I am able to upload my files to htdocs and view them on the localhost:8888, however when I make changes to a php file, the changes won't show up, only the original content of the php file remains.

The original file says:
and I see in the localhost : 8888
   Hello World.
However, when changing it to the following:
-- --
the localhost still prints:
   Hello World!
and not the changes to Hello Everyone!!! as the code specifies.

Can you please help,
Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some code ?

Comment: I advise you to use brew I was using MAMP too but when I discovered powers of homebrew I was blown away give it a try at least. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26493762/yosemite-php-gd-mcrypt-installation It is going to make you better at understanding apache2 and php and modules...

Comment: First: edit your question and insert the following informations: your file location path (complete path), your htdocs path and how you "upload your file to htdocs".

Answer (score 2):

Open MAMP, go to `Preferences` then `PHP tab` and set `Cache` option to `OFF`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the code is cached. You need to disable OPCache. If you're using MAMP PRO you can to this in the settings. Otherwise you need to edit the `php.ini` yourself.

Edit `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.x.x/conf/php.ini` by adding `;` as first character to all OPcache related lines. Where `5.x.x` needs to be the folder with your used PHP version. You can find out which version you're using by adding `phpinfo();` to your `index.php` file.

Alternatively you can try adding `opcache_reset();` in your file before `echo "Hello World!"` in your `index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

I also suspect OPCache needs to be disabled or reset in your file.  I also just upgraded to OS X Yosemite and I'm using MAMP and had a very similar problem.  Whenever I edited my php code and refreshed the page, the changes wouldn't take immediate effect.  There was about a 3-5 minute delay.

After determining it wasn't an issue with FireFox or Chrome cache, I started searching for MAMP settings as potential culprits.  Adding `opcache_reset();` to the top of the page fixed the issue immediately.  I recommend trying this yourself next to see if anything changes.