# How can I configure my Laravel application to load using MAMP?

Tags: apache, laravel, nginx, laravel-4, mamp

**Environment**

I use Mac OS X Yosemite, MAMP Version (3.0.7.3).

**Document Root**

I already set the document root to point to my `laravel/public` folder.

**Permission**

Some people recommend me to **chmod** my laravel folder entirely, I also did that as well by running `chmod  -R 777 laravel/`.

**Testing**

Go to : http://localhost:8888/ , all I get is white space

[image]

How do I get this to work ?

Comment: Check the server errors logs and see what it says...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death?rq=1

Comment: @TheShiftExchange : Thanks for your suggestion, I check my php.ini, I saw `error_log = "/Applications/MAMP/logs/php_error.log"` , then I go the path, I found my logs and I am researching on that error now.

Comment: Forget MAMP use homestead, or your own PHP build... You are wasting time because not a lot of users use MAMP these days (means not much help). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26493762/yosemite-php-gd-mcrypt-installation

Comment: Just a shot in the dark here, but is this a fresh installation of Laravel? If so, did you follow the [installation steps](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0) and are sure Laravel is installed correctly?

Comment: You need to run ``composer install`` in project folder.

Comment: @Bogdan : I had the project already. I used to develop it in the Windows Environments, and been fine the whole time using WAMP.

Comment: Have you tried running `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: @limonte : I did that I got this stupid [error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29318709/how-can-i-resolve-your-requirements-could-not-be-resolved-to-an-installable-set)

Comment: @Bogdan : I did that already. I got error a long the way.

Comment: Well on windows you have not much choice but stick with XAMP well WAMP, now you switched to Mac, so get real: either use homestead or brew yourself in... its 10 minutes of configuring. Have fun with MAMP.

Comment: Kyslik : I really appreciate your suggestion about **homestead**, I really like that. I will set that up real soon. Just curious, how long does it take you to get your homestead up and running ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem by running:

`composer update`  until I see:

[image]

The last thing is to go in to my **/laravel** folder and run :

`chmod -R 777 /app/storage`

Then Viola ! I see my site.

Comment: according docs also vendor folder needs permissions. good luck

Comment: I am sorry I thought you are L5 artisan. In 4.* you dont need permissions for vendor folder :)