# How can I resolve "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages" error?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

When I run `composer update` I receive some wired output.

[image]

Here is my composer.json look like.

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.", "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "repositories": [{
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/Zizaco/ardent.git"
    }],
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.3.*"
    },
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.*", 
        "laravelbook/ardent": "dev-master as 2.4.0", 
        "zizaco/entrust": "dev-master", 
        "sebklaus/profiler": "dev-master", 
        "doctrine/dbal": "dev-master"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations", "app/database/seeds", "app/tests",
            "app/libraries"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled", 
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled", 
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

How do I fix that ?

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message **in text form**, along with your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Your software dependencies have an incompatible version conflict.

At the same time you want to install any Laravel 4.2.x version, and "zizaco/entrust" from its master branch. And that master branch requires at least Laravel 5.0 (roughly speaking).

The problem comes from the dependency on branches. It's likely that the package zizaco/entrust once was using Laravel 4.2 in its master branch, and that you were able to install your dependencies at that day. But the very moment this branch gets updated with an incompatible version requirement, you will never ever be able to run `composer update` and get updated dependencies.

Always use tagged versions! Ideally you use a relaxed version requirement that allows for compatible updates. This should be expressed as a tilde-two-number version requirement: `~1.2` would install a version 1.2.0 and up (like 1.2.99 or 1.2.100), and also 1.3 and up. If you need a certain patch release: Caret-three-number version `^1.2.10` will install 1.2.10 or up, also 1.3 and up.

Using this version requirement instead of `dev-master` will allow you to use released versions instead of the unstable state in the master branch, and allows you to address the most recent version that still works with Laravel 4.2. I guess that would be zizaco/entrust version 1.3.0, but version 1.2 would also qualify. Go with `"zizaco/entrust": "~1.2"`.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what part of the error message made you think that `Laravel 5.0` was required by `zizaco/entrust`.

Comment: Well, if I remember correctly I was looking at the mentioned library and saw the requirements in it's composer.json. And I probably paraphrased what I saw because there was no explicit requirement, but some components of it. In the error message, you see that `illuminate/support ^5.0` is required by `zizaco/entrust`, and if you know that "Laravel" and "Illuminate" are basically the same thing, the conclusion should be correct.

Answer (score 322):

Run this command:

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

or

```
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
```

[Composer ignore-platform-reqs flag explanation](https://hannesvdvreken.com/2015/01/18/composer-ignore-platform-reqs-flag/)

Comment: Any disadvantage of using this?

Comment: @AdemTepe, please this https://hannesvdvreken.com/2015/01/18/composer-ignore-platform-reqs-flag/

Comment: This needs an explanation

Comment: These commands will install and update all the packages regardless of the version conflicts.

Answer (score 44):

I am facing the same issue. I am using 'Lumen' microservice framework.
I recently resolved the same issue by installing two packages:-

1. sudo apt-get install **php7.0-mbstring**,
2. sudo apt-get install **php7.0-xml** or sudo apt-get install **php-xml**

After installing this, you need to execute this command:-
**composer update**

Hope, it will resolve the issue. I work on my system.

Comment: People should never use composer update in production, this may cause problems. composer install is the right command to install. I downvoted you but I'm upvoting because 1 and 2 are correct.

Comment: In my situation installing php-gd did the trick. Composer didn't mention this anywhere in the failure output even with the verbose (-vvv) flag on.

Comment: I'm working on Ubuntu 20.04. Only running this command was sufficient:
`sudo apt-get install php-xml`

Comment: You may want to install curl as well `sudo apt-get install php-curl`

Answer (score 26):

The simplest solution is adding `--ignore-platform-reqs` flag.

> If you are running `composer install` or `composer update` use it with `--ignore-platform-reqs` flag

**Example**

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Or

```
composer update --ignore-platform-reqs
```

And this should do the trick!

Answer (score 17):

I use **Windows 10** machine working with **PHP 8** and **Lavarel 8** and I got the same error, I used the following command :-

`composer update --ignore-platform-reqs`

to update all the packages regardless of the version conflicts.

Answer (score 9):

Were those `dev-master`s added automatically? Avoid them as unnecessary version constraints, for 'any suitable version' use `"*"`, or `"@dev"` if you don't mind dev packages. My guess is that Entrust is the potential troublemaker.

Also, `"minimum-stability": "stable"` imposes additional constraints, and

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true
```

is more conflict-free, consider it a rule of thumb.

Comment: The problem is the usage of unstable dev versions. Blindly allowing them (even if preferring stable) is the key to an unmaintainable mess.

Comment: @Sven The answer addresses the problem directly, which is `dev-master` constraint. It doesn't state that loose version constraints are good - they will probably result in a mess, and this is on developer's conscience. The fact that the answer isn't opinionated about tagging doesn't make it wrong. I Thanks for a downvote, by the way. That's quite ethical to downvote neighbouring answers.

Answer (score 7):

I solved the same issue setting `'laravel/framework'` dependency version from `"^8.0"` to `"^7.0"`.

After that running `composer update --ignore-platform-reqs` simply worked

[composer.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVwJf.png)

Comment: As of today, the latest Laravel framework version is 7.10. So how did your dependency went up to 8.0?

Comment: not sure honestly since I’m pretty new with Laravel. It was a brand new installation with messing with the composer.json file

Answer (score 7):

I am facing the same issue in Laravel v8.49.0 (PHP v8.0.6).              Using Composer through install packages
I recently resolved the same issue by installing two packages:-
composer create-project laravel/laravel myapp

[image: your requirement could not be resolved]

Composer Update

`composer update --ignore-platform-reqs`

OR
`composer install --ignore-platform-reqs`

Check Start Server
`php artisan serve`

[image]

Comment: server started and get "No Application Encryption Key Has Been Specified"  check this         https://stackoverflow.com/a/68219720/12635334

Comment: Prefer [text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) for accessibility and many other reasons.

Answer (score 3):

Install the following according to the PHP version installed on your system:

```
sudo apt-get install php8.0-curl php8.0-gd php8.0-xsl php8.0-dom
```

Finally try again to create the laravel project with composer

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel myProject
```

Comment: very good.......

Answer (score 3):

You must be in the correct directory so cd into it, then:
`composer update --ignore-platform-reqs` if you have previous installed composer as Vivek M suggests. My problem was wrong directory.
cd into: xampp/htdocs/laravelProjects/laravelP1

Answer (score 2):

> ## This solution has been tested on Windows OS

- Verify that **PHP** `c:/php/bin/` exist in the environment path variable or *drive:/path/php/bin/* and type `php --version` in terminal, command prompt or Windows PowerShell to make sure output matches to the following one.
  [image]
  [Download PHP](https://www.php.net/downloads.php)
- Verify that **Composer** is installed by typing `composer` in the terminal, command prompt, or Windows PowerShell matches the following output.
  [image]
  [Download Composer](https://getcomposer.org/download/)
- Make sure to type the correct command for initializing the Laravel project:
  `composer create-project laravel/laravel ProjectName`
  Click [here](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/quick) to read official docs.

---

> ### If you're still getting errors, just follow the solution for Laravel:

1. Just open the file `c:/php/php.ini` in any text editor
2. Find the `;extension=fileinfo` statement
3. Uncomment it, remove semi-colon (;) from the start, just make it `extension=fileinfo`
4. Save the file

Answer (score 1):

Add `"barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.7.3"` at the end of `require` array inside composer.json

Save composer.json and run `composer update`

You are done !

Comment: People should never use composer update to install dependencies. It should use composer install. Composer update will update all dependencies and that could be catastrophic.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same error, by adding `"zizaco/entrust": "*"` instead of the `"zizaco/entrust": "~1.2"`.

Answer (score 1):

I also meet this when trying to create laravel project, try this and it may works for you as well

Change from

```
;extension=fileinfo
```

to

```
extension=fileinfo
```

Comment: This one works for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
"config": {
  "platform": {
    "ext-pcntl": "7.2",
    "ext-posix": "7.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem in Laravel 5.8, what I did was to do `composer require` for each library and all where installed correctly.

Like so:

instead of adding it to the composer.json file or specifying a version:

```
composer require msurguy/honeypot: dev-master
```

I instead did without specifying any version:

```
composer require msurguy/honeypot
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **php ^8.0**

open list of available php versions

```
   sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

switch to on of the older versions above **PHP 7.2**, select one of them
then update composer

```
composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem has been resolved by removing `composer.lock` and re running composer

Answer (score -1):

run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-sodium '

run this command

```
composer update --ignore-platform-req=ext-sodium
```

Comment: Please don't duplicate existing answers, especially as the error message doesn't mention any missing extensions

Answer (score -2):

**CAUSE:**

The error is happening because your project folder is owned by the root user.

**SOLUTION**

Change ownership to the currently signed in user and not the root user. If you only have root as the sole user, create another user with root privileges.

$ sudo chown -R **current_user** /my/project/directory/

then

$ composer install

Answer (score -7):

Just activate the curl in the php.ini file

```
;extension=php_curl.dll
```

to

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

and then **composer install**

Comment: I'm not quite sure what activating php_curl.dll will do for a version mismatch (Laravel 4.x vs Laravel 5.x). Can you explain how this would solve the question?

Comment: I was having the problem described above, so I activated the curl and the problem was solved. I believe that the composer or laravel uses this php extension to download the packages. In my case it would not be exactly incompatible of the laravel packages, it would just be a difficulty for the composer to download the packages.