# How to Create Magento-2 Extension Package to upload on Magento-2 official site?

Tags: php, magento, module, composer-php, magento2

I develop a extension in Magento-2. When a upload this extension on Magento official site then they send some errors in package.When I check this in production mode it is not showing any error.Please help me to create correct package of the Magento-2 extension.

**Errors**

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- Installation request for magento/magento2ce 2.0.13 -> satisfiable by magento/magento2ce[2.0.13].
- company/module-extensionname 1.0.0 requires magento/framework 100.1.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.1.4, 100.1.5, 100.1.6, 100.1.7].
- don't install magento/framework 100.1.0-rc1|remove magento/magento2ce 2.0.13
- don't install magento/framework 100.1.0-rc2|remove magento/magento2ce 2.0.13
- don't install magento/framework 100.1.0-rc3|remove magento/magento2ce 2.0.13
- don't install magento/framework 100.1.0|remove magento/magento2ce 2.0.13
- don't install magento/framework 100.1.1|remove magento/magento2ce 2.0.13
- don't install magento/framework 100.1.2|remove magento/magento2ce 2.0.13
- don't install magento/framework 100.1.3|remove magento/magento2ce 2.0.13
- don't install magento/framework 100.1.4|remove magento/magento2ce 2.0.13
- don't install magento/framework 100.1.5|remove magento/magento2ce 2.0.13
- don't install magento/framework 100.1.6|remove magento/magento2ce 2.0.13
- don't install magento/framework 100.1.7|remove magento/magento2ce 2.0.13
- Installation request for comapny/module-extensionname 1.0.0 -> satisfiable by comapny/module-extensionname[1.0.0].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] sh
[DockerOperationsPHP70Magento20CEVarnish] Running shell script
+ echo Failure
```

**composer.json**

```
{
  "name": "company/module-extensionname",
  "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.",
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
    "magento/framework": "100.1.*"
  },
  "authors": [
    {
      "name": "Tomas Jindal",
      "email": "test@test.com",
      "homepage": "https://stackoverflow.com",
      "role": "Developer"
    }
  ],
  "autoload": {
    "files": [ "registration.php" ],
    "psr-4": {
      "company\\extensionname\\": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I resolve "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29318709/how-can-i-resolve-your-requirements-could-not-be-resolved-to-an-installable-set)

Answer (score 4):

Give proper extension name  For example you make extension name is
**Requestquote**  and you give name **RequestQuote** this is not acceptable in magento market place.

follow the below link and make composer.json file

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105533/how-to-create-extension-package-in-magento-2