# Error when running composer install command

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

when I run

```
php composer.phar install
```

i have this error

> Dependency resolution completed in 0.476 seconds
>
> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
>   packages
>
> Problem 1
>    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/cache v4.2.3
>
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/cache v4.2.2
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/cache v4.2.1
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/cache v4.2.0
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/cache v4.1.11
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/cache v4.1.10
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/cache v4.1.9
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/cache v4.1.8
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/cache v4.1.7
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/cache v4.1.6
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/cache v4.1.5
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/cache v4.1.4
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/cache v4.1.3
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/cache v4.1.2
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/cache v4.1.1
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/cache v4.1.0
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/cache v4.0.15
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/cache v4.0.14
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/cache v4.0.13
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/cache v4.0.12
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/cache v4.0.11
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/cache v4.0.10
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/cache v4.0.9
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/cache v4.0.8
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/cache v4.0.7
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/cache v4.0.6
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/cache v4.0.5
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/cache v4.0.4
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/cache v4.0.3
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/cache v4.0.2
> - Conclusion: don't install symfony/cache v4.0.1
> - don't install symfony/cache v4.0.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.0
> - don't install symfony/cache v4.0.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.1
> - don't install symfony/cache v4.0.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.10
> - don't install symfony/cache v4.0.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.11
> - don't install symfony/cache v4.0.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.12
> - don't install symfony/cache v4.0.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.13
> - don't install symfony/cache v4.0.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.14
> - don't install symfony/cache v4.0.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.15
> - don't install symfony/cache v4.0.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.16
> - don't install symfony/cache v4.0.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.17
> - don't install symfony/cache v4.0.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.18
> - don't install symfony/cache v4.0.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.19
> - don't install symfony/cache v4.0.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.2
> - don't install symfony/cache v4.0.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.20
> - don't install symfony/cache v4.0.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.21
> - don't install symfony/cache v4.0.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.22
> - don't install symfony/cache v4.0.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.3
> - don't install symfony/cache v4.0.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.4
> - don't install symfony/cache v4.0.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.5
> - don't install symfony/cache v4.0.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.6
> - don't install symfony/cache v4.0.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.7
> - don't install symfony/cache v4.0.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.8
> - don't install symfony/cache v4.0.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.4.9
> - Installation request for symfony/cache ^4.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/cache[v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.10, v4.0.11, v4.0.12, v4.0.13,
>     v4.0.14, v4.0.15, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v4.0.4, v4.0.5, v4.0.6, v4.0.7,
>     v4.0.8, v4.0.9, v4.1.0, v4.1.1, v4.1.10, v4.1.11, v4.1.2, v4.1.3,
>     v4.1.4, v4.1.5, v4.1.6, v4.1.7, v4.1.8, v4.1.9, v4.2.0, v4.2.1,
>     v4.2.2, v4.2.3].
> - Installation request for symfony/symfony 3.4.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.4.0, v3.4.1, v3.4.10, v3.4.11, v3.4.12, v3.4.13,
>     v3.4.14, v3.4.15, v3.4.16, v3.4.17, v3.4.18, v3.4.19, v3.4.2, v3.4.20,
>     v3.4.21, v3.4.22, v3.4.3, v3.4.4, v3.4.5, v3.4.6, v3.4.7, v3.4.8,
>     v3.4.9].

**this is the require part in the composer.json**

```
 {
    "php": ">=7.0",
    "alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter": "^1.1",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.9",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "3.0.2",
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "^1.1.7",
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "^3.4.0",
    "firebase/php-jwt": "^5.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "^2.2",
    "friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle": "dev-master",
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "^2.3",
    "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "^2.4",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.1",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "league/omnipay": "^3.0",
    "nelmio/cors-bundle": "^1.5",
    "omnipay/stripe": "dev-patch-1",
    "phramz/doctrine-annotation-scanner": "^1.0",
    "ramsey/uuid": "^3.8",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "^2.8",
    "symfony/cache": "^4.0",
    "symfony/expression-language": "^4.0",
    "symfony/ldap": "^4.1",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
    "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^3.2",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.4.*",
    "twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"
}
```

Any one can help me please ?

Comment: Try to delete your composer.lock and vendor folder and then retry.

Comment: i have the same error

Comment: There's another solution but it will take some time. You must install every dependency separately. Delete all dependencies from your composer.json and install them this  way: `composer require dependency:version`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I resolve "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29318709/how-can-i-resolve-your-requirements-could-not-be-resolved-to-an-installable-set)

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you have defined `"symfony/symfony": "3.4.*"` in your `composer.json`, but you are also requiring `"symfony/cache": "^4.0"`. The issue with that is the `4.0` version is only compatible with symfony versions greater or equal `4.0`.

So you should downgrade your `symfony/cache` version to `3.4` like this:

```
{
    ...
    "symfony/cache": "^3.4",
    "symfony/symfony": "3.4.*",
    ...
}
```

Comment: That's basically useless though as the `symfony/symfony` package already comes with `symfony/cache` included. So you could as well just omit the `symfony/cache` dependency.