# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. Composer update error

Tags: php, laravel

When I run `composer update` I get this error:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I resolve "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29318709/how-can-i-resolve-your-requirements-could-not-be-resolved-to-an-installable-set)

Comment: I know  this answer. But not working for me this variant.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're using WAMP and the issue is that you're missing PHP curl extension. 
Please try installing and enabling curl extension: 
[How to enable curl in Wamp server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021536/how-to-enable-curl-in-wamp-server)
And the above issue should be gone.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But not working. 1. I could not find in the .ini file
2. I changed {extention=Curl} for your example
3. is this correct ??

Comment: you just probably have wamp installed in different location
find where did you install wamp into and find the php.ini file there

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/mdtGYUH_7_heeQ see please this link. This is way to .ini file. is Correct??

Comment: sorry, i can't access you're img as yandex is blocked on my network

Comment: ok thank you all exactly. I found a solution. The problem was in the path. It connected to c:\php7.3.11\php.ini   ...   but should have been on Wamp path.Thank you much.

Comment: no worries, i am glad you fixed it and can proceed to more interesting stuff - coding :) good luck

Comment: Instead of answering with a link to another question, please flag the question as a duplicate. Thanks

Comment: @Machavity gotcha, will try to be more thoughtful next time.