# Laravel 6.16 shopping cart

Tags: php, laravel

Please i'm using laravel 6.16. I tried installing laravel shopping cart but failed. Any help please?

**This is the error I got** after entering `composer require "darryldecode/cart:~2.0"`

```
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for gloudemans/shoppingcart ^2.6 -> satisfiable by gloudemans/shoppingcart[2.6.0].
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - gloudemans/shoppingcart 2.6.0 requires illuminate/events 5.1.* || 5.2.* || 5.3.* || 5.4.* || 5.5.*|| 5.6.* || 5.7.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/events[
5.1.x-dev, 5.2.x-dev, 5.3.x-dev, 5.4.x-dev, 5.5.x-dev, 5.6.x-dev, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.x-dev, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.
25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2
.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27, v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2,
 v5.5.28, v5.5.33, v5.5.34, v5.5.35, v5.5.36, v5.5.37, v5.5.39, v5.5.40, v5.5.41, v5.5.43, v5.5.44, v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.1
4, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6
.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11,
 v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9].
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.2.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.3.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.4.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.5.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.7.17|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.7.18|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.7.19|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events 5.7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.13|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.16|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.20|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.22|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.25|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.28|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.30|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.31|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.41|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.6|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.1.8|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.19|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.21|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.24|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.25|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.26|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.27|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.28|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.31|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.32|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.37|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.43|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.45|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.6|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.2.7|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.3.16|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.3.23|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.3.4|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.4.13|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.4.17|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.4.19|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.4.27|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.4.36|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.4.9|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.16|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.17|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.28|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.33|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.34|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.35|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.36|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.37|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.39|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.40|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.41|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.43|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.5.44|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.10|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.11|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.12|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.13|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.14|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.15|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.16|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.17|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.19|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.20|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.21|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.22|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.23|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.24|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.25|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.26|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.27|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.28|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.29|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.3|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.30|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.31|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.32|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.33|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.34|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.35|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.36|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.37|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.38|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.39|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.4|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.5|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.6|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.7|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.8|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.6.9|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.1|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.10|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.11|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.15|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.20|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.21|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.22|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.23|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.26|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.27|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.28|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.3|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.4|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.5|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.6|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.7|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.8|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - don't install illuminate/events v5.7.9|don't install laravel/framework v6.16.0
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v6.16.0, required as ^6.2) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.16.0].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I resolve "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29318709/how-can-i-resolve-your-requirements-could-not-be-resolved-to-an-installable-set)

Comment: Welcome, I edited your question to make it a bit easier to read. The most important parts of the error are at the top where it says "Your requirements could not be resolved..." and at the end where it shows which requirements conflict. A search for these will reveal that other people have asked about conflicting requirements before. You'll probably find answers if you look at those questions.

Comment: Because v2 is for Laravel 5.1. You're using Laravel 6^ so you need the latest version: `composer require "darryldecode/cart"`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue is with `gloudemans/shoppingcart`. As far as I know that package does not support `laravel 6.x`.

Can you check your `composer.json` to see if it contains `gloudemans/shoppingcart`. 
If it does, remove it and try again.