# composer require illuminate/support gives an error like "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages."

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I am using laravel 6.18...
I need to install package "composer require illuminate/support" but some how got an error.I need to install package "composer require illuminate/support" but some how got an error.I need to install package "composer require illuminate/support" but some how got an error.

My Error

```
A composer dependency is missing

You might be missing a composer dependency. A possible package that was found is illuminate/support.

See if this is the package that you need and install it via composer require illuminate/support.
```

Below is the error

```
Problem 1
- Conclusion: don't install illuminate/support v7.18.0
- Conclusion: don't install illuminate/support 7.x-dev
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[7.x-dev, 6.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.10.0, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.10.1, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.11.0, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.12.0, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.13.0, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.13.1, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.14.0, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.15.0, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.15.1, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.16.0, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.17.0, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.17.1, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.18.0, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.18.1, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.18.10, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.18.11, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.18.12, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.18.13, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.18.14, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.18.15, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.18.16, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.18.17, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.18.18, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.18.19, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.18.2, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.18.20, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.18.21, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.18.22, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.18.23, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.18.3, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.18.4, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.18.5, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.18.6, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.18.7, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.18.8, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.18.9, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.3.0, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.4.0, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.4.1, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.5.0, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.5.1, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.5.2, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.6.0, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.6.1, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.6.2, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.7.0, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.8.0, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v6.9.0, 7.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[7.x-dev, v6.18.23].
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[7.x-dev, v6.18.23].
- Installation request for illuminate/support ^7.18 -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[7.x-dev, v7.18.0], laravel/framework[7.x-dev].
- Installation request for laravel/framework ^6.3 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[6.x-dev, v6.10.0, v6.10.1, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.10, v6.18.11, v6.18.12, v6.18.13, v6.18.14, v6.18.15, v6.18.16, v6.18.17, v6.18.18, v6.18.19, v6.18.2, v6.18.20, v6.18.21, v6.18.22, v6.18.23, v6.18.3, v6.18.4, v6.18.5, v6.18.6, v6.18.7, v6.18.8, v6.18.9, v6.3.0, v6.4.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0, v6.9.0].
```

my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "rappasoft/laravel-boilerplate",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Boilerplate Project.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel",
        "boilerplate"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2",
        "albertcht/invisible-recaptcha": "^1.9",
        "altek/accountant": "^1.2",
        "altek/eventually": "^1.0",
        "arcanedev/log-viewer": "^5.0",
        "creativeorange/gravatar": "~1.0",
        "davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs": "^5.0",
        "facade/ignition": "^1.11",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "lab404/laravel-impersonate": "^1.4",
        "langleyfoxall/laravel-nist-password-rules": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.3",
        "laravel/passport": "^9.3",
        "laravel/socialite": "^4.1",
        "spatie/laravel-html": "^2.22",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^3.0",
        "torann/geoip": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.2",
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.6",
        "codedungeon/phpunit-result-printer": "^0.26.1",
        "facade/ignition-code-editor": "^1.0",
        "facade/ignition-self-diagnosis": "^1.0",
        "facade/ignition-tinker-tab": "^1.0",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "^2.14",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.0",
        "roave/security-advisories": "dev-master"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi",
            "@php artisan ide-helper:generate",
            "@php artisan ide-helper:meta"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ],
        "clear-all": [
            "@php artisan clear-compiled",
            "@php artisan cache:clear",
            "@php artisan route:clear",
            "@php artisan view:clear",
            "@php artisan config:clear",
            "composer dumpautoload -o"
        ],
        "cache-all": [
            "@php artisan config:cache",
            "@php artisan route:cache"
        ],
        "cc": [
            "composer clear-all",
            "composer cache-all"
        ],
        "phpunit": [
            "phpunit > output.txt -d memory_limit=2048M"
        ],
        "coverage-xml": [
            "phpunit --coverage-clover ./coverage.xml"
        ],
        "coverage-html": [
            "phpunit --coverage-html ./coverage"
        ],
        "coverage-text": [
            "phpunit --coverage-text"
        ],
        "format": [
            "php-cs-fixer fix --show-progress=estimating --config=.php_cs.dist"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: The `laravel/framework` already has `illuminate/support` included. If you have the framework installed (which you do) you don't need to install `illuminate/support` separately.

Comment: Did you try to install the 6.18 version? Illuminate packages requires to be in the same version as laravel, the logs indicates you are trying to install the version 7.x

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I resolve "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29318709/how-can-i-resolve-your-requirements-could-not-be-resolved-to-an-installable-set)

Comment: @manuerumx..yes i also tried " composer require illuminate/support "v6.18.0"" but giving me same error

Answer (score 0):

The laravel/framework already has illuminate/support included. If you have the framework installed (which you do) you cannot install another version of illuminate/support separately as it will cause conflicts in PSR-4 namespacing. This is something that can be done in node but not in composer with PHP.