# Cannot Install packages in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

iam trying to install jasperPHP (composer require cossou/jasperphp) in laravel but i got this error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for agoalofalife/reports ^0.3.0 -> satisfiable by agoalofalife/reports[v0.3.0].
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - agoalofalife/reports v0.3.0 requires maatwebsite/excel ~2.1.0 -> satisfiable by maatwebsite/excel[2.1.10, 2.1.11, 2.1.12, 2.1.13, 2.1.14, 2.1.15, 2.1.16, 2.1.17, 2.1.18, 2.1.19, 2.1.20, 2.1.21, 2.1.22, 2.1.23, 2.1.24, 2.1.25, 2.1.26, 2.1.27, 2.1.28, 2.1.29, 2.1.30, 2.1.4, 2.1.5, 2.1.6, 2.1.7, 2.1.8, 2.1.9, 2.1.x-dev, v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.2, v2.1.3].
   
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.5.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.16|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.17|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.2|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.28|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.33|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.34|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.35|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.36|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.37|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.39|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.40|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.41|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.43|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.5.44|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.10|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.11|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.12|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.13|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.14|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.15|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.16|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.17|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.19|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.2|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.20|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.21|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.22|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.23|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.24|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.25|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.26|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.27|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.28|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.29|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.3|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.30|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.31|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.32|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.33|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.34|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.35|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.36|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.37|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.38|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.39|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.4|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.5|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.6|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.7|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.8|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.6.9|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.17|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.18|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.19|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.7.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.1|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.10|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.11|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.15|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.2|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.20|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.21|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.22|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.23|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.26|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.27|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.28|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.3|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.4|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.5|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.6|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.7|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.8|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.7.9|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.8.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.11|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.12|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.14|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.15|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.17|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.18|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.19|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.2|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.20|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.22|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.24|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.27|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.28|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.29|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.3|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.30|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.31|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.32|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.33|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.34|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.35|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.36|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.4|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.8|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.8.9|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.0.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.1.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.2.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.3.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support 5.4.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.22|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.25|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.26|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.28|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.33|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.13|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.16|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.20|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.22|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.25|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.28|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.30|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.31|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.41|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.6|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.8|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.19|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.21|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.24|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.25|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.26|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.27|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.28|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.31|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.32|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.37|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.43|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.45|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.6|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.7|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.16|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.23|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.3.4|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.13|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.17|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.19|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.27|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.36|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.4.9|don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v7.26.1, required as ^7.24) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.26.1].

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Comment: "_don't install laravel/framework v7.26.1_" jasperphp seems to be a Laravel 5 package

Comment: excuse me .. iam new in laravel .. what should i do

Comment: I think there is a clearer answer to this here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29318709/how-can-i-resolve-your-requirements-could-not-be-resolved-to-an-installable-set

Answer (score 1):

The package is `abandoned` and not maintained anymore.

Try to install the recommended package ([url](https://packagist.org/packages/quilhasoft/jasperphp)) by the author