# upgrading to laravel 10 and can not seem to find the correct aws-sdk

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I am upgrading from laravel 8 to 10 and to php 8.2

I cleared out my composer.json and painfully added each package via "composer require" so i could get all the correct versions.

My last stumbling block in getting aws S3 to work. I can not seem to find a package that will work with laravel 10 dependancies.

Has any one got it to work with v10 and s3?

The package i used with laravel 8 sociallydev/spaces-api has some old dependancies that can not work with v10.

I tried

```
composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 ~1.0

 Problem 1
- league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3[1.0.0, ..., 1.0.13] require league/flysystem ~1.0 -> found league/flysystem[1.0.0, ..., 1.1.10] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^3.15.1).
- league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3[1.0.15, ..., 1.0.30] require league/flysystem ^1.0.40 -> found league/flysystem[1.0.40, ..., 1.1.10] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^3.15.1).
- Root composer.json requires league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 ~1.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3[1.0.0, ..., 1.0.30].
```

i also tried

```
composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 ~3.0
Problem 1
- league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3[3.12.1, ..., 3.15.0] require aws/aws-sdk-php ^3.220.0 -> satisfiable by aws/aws-sdk-php[3.220.0, ..., 3.275.4].
- league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3[3.0.0, ..., 3.10.3] require aws/aws-sdk-php ^3.132.4 -> satisfiable by aws/aws-sdk-php[3.132.4, ..., 3.275.4].
- aws/aws-sdk-php[3.132.4, ..., 3.173.19] require guzzlehttp/psr7 ^1.4.1 -> found guzzlehttp/psr7[1.4.1, ..., 1.9.1] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^2.5.0).
- aws/aws-sdk-php[3.173.20, ..., 3.198.8] require guzzlehttp/psr7 ^1.7.0 -> found guzzlehttp/psr7[1.7.0, ..., 1.9.1] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^2.5.0).
- aws/aws-sdk-php[3.199.0, ..., 3.275.4] require guzzlehttp/promises ^1.4.0 -> found guzzlehttp/promises[1.4.0, ..., 1.5.3] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^2.0.0).
- Root composer.json requires league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 ~3.0 -> satisfiable by league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3[3.0.0, ..., 3.15.0].
```

and finally

```
composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3
Problem 1
- league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3[3.12.1, ..., 3.15.0] require aws/aws-sdk-php ^3.220.0 -> satisfiable by aws/aws-sdk-php[3.220.0, ..., 3.275.4].
- league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3[3.0.0, ..., 3.10.3] require aws/aws-sdk-php ^3.132.4 -> satisfiable by aws/aws-sdk-php[3.132.4, ..., 3.275.4].
- league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3[1.0.0, ..., 1.0.13] require league/flysystem ~1.0 -> found league/flysystem[1.0.0, ..., 1.1.10] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^3.15.1).
- league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3[1.0.15, ..., 1.0.30] require league/flysystem ^1.0.40 -> found league/flysystem[1.0.40, ..., 1.1.10] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^3.15.1).
- league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3[2.0.0, ..., 2.5.0] require league/flysystem ^2.0.0 -> found league/flysystem[2.0.0, ..., 2.5.0] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^3.15.1).
- aws/aws-sdk-php[3.131.0, ..., 3.173.19] require guzzlehttp/psr7 ^1.4.1 -> found guzzlehttp/psr7[1.4.1, ..., 1.9.1] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^2.5.0).
- aws/aws-sdk-php[3.173.20, ..., 3.198.8] require guzzlehttp/psr7 ^1.7.0 -> found guzzlehttp/psr7[1.7.0, ..., 1.9.1] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^2.5.0).
- aws/aws-sdk-php[3.199.0, ..., 3.275.4] require guzzlehttp/promises ^1.4.0 -> found guzzlehttp/promises[1.4.0, ..., 1.5.3] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^2.0.0).
- Root composer.json requires league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 * -> satisfiable by league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3[1.0.0, ..., 1.0.30, 2.0.0, ..., 2.5.0, 3.0.0, ..., 3.15.0].
```

here is my composer.json

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"type": "project",
"description": "The skeleton application for the Laravel framework.",
"keywords": ["laravel", "framework"],
"license": "MIT",
"require": {
    "asm89/stack-cors": "*",
    "brick/math": "*",
    "dnoegel/php-xdg-base-dir": "*",
    "doctrine/inflector": "^2.0",
    "doctrine/instantiator": "^2.0",
    "doctrine/lexer": "^3.0",
    "dragonmantank/cron-expression": "^3.3",
    "egulias/email-validator": "^4.0",
    "elic-dev/laravel-site-protection": "^1.1",
    "facade/ignition-contracts": "^1.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.7.0",
    "guzzlehttp/promises": "^2.0.0",
    "guzzlehttp/psr7": "^2.5.0",
    "hamcrest/hamcrest-php": "^2.0",
    "laravel/framework": "^10.10",
    "laravel/sanctum": "^3.2",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.8",
    "laravel/ui": "^4.2",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^6.4",
    "league/commonmark": "^2.4",
    "league/flysystem": "^3.15.1",
    "monolog/monolog": "^3.4",
    "myclabs/deep-copy": "^1.11",
    "nesbot/carbon": "^2.68",
    "nikic/php-parser": "^4.16",
    "opis/closure": "^3.6",
    "phar-io/manifest": "^2.0",
    "phar-io/version": "^3.2",
    "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.3",
    "phpdocumentor/type-resolver": "^1.7",
    "phpoption/phpoption": "^1.9",
    "phpspec/prophecy": "^1.1",
    "psr/container": "^2.0",
    "psr/event-dispatcher": "^1.0",
    "psr/http-message": "^1.0.1",
    "psr/log": "^3.0",
    "psr/simple-cache": "^3.0",
    "psy/psysh": "^0.11.18",
    "ralouphie/getallheaders": "^3.0",
    "ramsey/collection": "^2.0",
    "ramsey/uuid": "^4.7",
    "sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup": "^3.0",
    "sebastian/comparator": "^5.0",
    "sebastian/diff": "^5.0",
    "sebastian/environment": "^6.0",
    "sebastian/exporter": "^5.0",
    "sebastian/global-state": "^6.0",
    "sebastian/object-enumerator": "^5.0",
    "sebastian/object-reflector": "^3.0",
    "sebastian/recursion-context": "^5.0",
    "sebastian/resource-operations": "^3.0",
    "sebastian/type": "^4.0",
    "sebastian/version": "^4.0",
    "spatie/laravel-permission": "^5.10",
    "spatie/laravel-sluggable": "*",
    "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "^5.4",
    "symfony/css-selector": "^6.3",
    "symfony/deprecation-contracts": "^3.3",
    "symfony/error-handler": "^6.3",
    "symfony/event-dispatcher": "^6.3",
    "symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts": "^3.3",
    "symfony/finder": "^6.3",
    "symfony/http-foundation": "^6.3",
    "symfony/http-kernel": "^6.3",
    "symfony/mime": "^6.3",
    "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "^1.27",
    "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "^1.27",
    "symfony/polyfill-intl-grapheme": "^1.27",
    "symfony/polyfill-intl-idn": "^1.27",
    "symfony/polyfill-intl-normalizer": "^1.27",
    "symfony/polyfill-mbstring": "^1.27",
    "symfony/polyfill-php72": "^1.27",
    "symfony/polyfill-php73": "^1.27",
    "symfony/polyfill-php80": "^1.27",
    "symfony/process": "^6.3",
    "symfony/routing": "^6.3",
    "symfony/service-contracts": "^3.3",
    "symfony/string": "^6.3",
    "symfony/translation": "^6.3",
    "symfony/translation-contracts": "^3.3",
    "symfony/var-dumper": "^6.3",
    "theseer/tokenizer": "^1.2",
    "tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles": "^2.2",
    "vemcogroup/laravel-sparkpost-driver": "^5.0.5",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^5.5",
    "voku/portable-ascii": "^2.0",
    "webmozart/assert": "^1.11"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
    "laravel/sail": "^1.18",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^7.7",
    "phpdocumentor/reflection-common": "^2.2",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.1",
    "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.0"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": []
    }
},
"config": {
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "allow-plugins": {
        "pestphp/pest-plugin": true,
        "php-http/discovery": true
    }
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"prefer-stable": true
```

}

here is the original version of the required list

```
   "require": {
    "asm89/stack-cors": "^1.3.0",
    "brick/math": "^0.8.15",
    "dnoegel/php-xdg-base-dir": "^0.1.1",
    "doctrine/inflector": "^2.0.3",
    "doctrine/instantiator": "^1.3.1",
    "doctrine/lexer": "^1.2.1",
    "dragonmantank/cron-expression": "^2.3.0",
    "egulias/email-validator": "^2.1.18",
    "elic-dev/laravel-site-protection": "^1.1",
    "facade/flare-client-php": "^1.3.2",
    "facade/ignition": "^2.0.7",
    "facade/ignition-contracts": "^1.0.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4.0",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^1.0.6",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.5.5",
    "guzzlehttp/promises": "^1.3.1",
    "guzzlehttp/psr7": "^1.6.1",
    "hamcrest/hamcrest-php": "^2.0.0",
    "laravel/framework": "^7.19.0",
    "laravel/socialite": "^5.2",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.4.0",
    "laravel/ui": "^2.1.0",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^6.1.2",
    "league/commonmark": "^1.5.1",
    "league/flysystem": "^1.0.69",
    "monolog/monolog": "^2.1.0",
    "myclabs/deep-copy": "^1.10.1",
    "nesbot/carbon": "^2.36.1",
    "nikic/php-parser": "^4.6.0",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
    "opis/closure": "^3.5.5",
    "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "1.14",
    "phar-io/manifest": "^1.0.3",
    "phar-io/version": "^2.0.1",
    "phpdocumentor/reflection-common": "^2.2.0",
    "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^5.1.0",
    "phpdocumentor/type-resolver": "^1.3.0",
    "phpoption/phpoption": "^1.7.4",
    "phpspec/prophecy": "^1.10.3",
    "psr/container": "^1.0.0",
    "psr/event-dispatcher": "^1.0.0",
    "psr/http-message": "^1.0.1",
    "psr/log": "^1.1.3",
    "psr/simple-cache": "^1.0.1",
    "psy/psysh": "^0.10.4",
    "ralouphie/getallheaders": "^3.0.3",
    "ramsey/collection": "^1.0.1",
    "ramsey/uuid": "^4.0.1",
    "sebastian/code-unit-reverse-lookup": "^1.0.1",
    "sebastian/comparator": "^3.0.2",
    "sebastian/diff": "^3.0.2",
    "sebastian/environment": "^4.2.3",
    "sebastian/exporter": "^3.1.2",
    "sebastian/global-state": "^2.0.0",
    "sebastian/object-enumerator": "^3.0.3",
    "sebastian/object-reflector": "^1.1.1",
    "sebastian/recursion-context": "^3.0.0",
    "sebastian/resource-operations": "^2.0.1",
    "sebastian/type": "^1.1.3",
    "sebastian/version": "^2.0.1",
    "sociallydev/spaces-api": "v2",
    "spatie/laravel-permission": "^3.13.0",
    "spatie/laravel-sluggable": "^2.2",
    "square/square": "12.0.0.20210616",
    "swiftmailer/swiftmailer": "^6.2.3",
    "symfony/css-selector": "^5.1.2",
    "symfony/deprecation-contracts": "^2.1.3",
    "symfony/error-handler": "^5.1.2",
    "symfony/event-dispatcher": "^5.1.2",
    "symfony/event-dispatcher-contracts": "^2.1.3",
    "symfony/finder": "^5.1.2",
    "symfony/http-foundation": "^5.1.2",
    "symfony/http-kernel": "^5.1.2",
    "symfony/mime": "^5.1.2",
    "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "^1.17.1",
    "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "^1.17.1",
    "symfony/polyfill-intl-grapheme": "^1.17.1",
    "symfony/polyfill-intl-idn": "^1.17.1",
    "symfony/polyfill-intl-normalizer": "^1.17.1",
    "symfony/polyfill-mbstring": "^1.17.1",
    "symfony/polyfill-php72": "^1.17.0",
    "symfony/polyfill-php73": "^1.17.1",
    "symfony/polyfill-php80": "^1.17.1",
    "symfony/process": "^5.1.2",
    "symfony/routing": "^5.1.2",
    "symfony/service-contracts": "^2.1.3",
    "symfony/string": "^5.1.2",
    "symfony/translation": "^5.1.2",
    "symfony/translation-contracts": "^2.1.3",
    "symfony/var-dumper": "^5.1.2",
    "theseer/tokenizer": "^1.1.3",
    "tijsverkoyen/css-to-inline-styles": "^2.2.2",
    "vemcogroup/laravel-sparkpost-driver": "4.x",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^4.1.7",
    "voku/portable-ascii": "^1.5.2",
    "webmozart/assert": "^1.9.0"
},
```

Comment: can you paste your composer file ?

Comment: basically you have a dependency (let's call it A) in your composer.json that is locked to an obsolete version and you are requiring another dependency (B) that requires A to be updated (or vice versa). Please post your `composer.json` file.

Comment: @IGP thanks, composer.json posted

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I resolve "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29318709/how-can-i-resolve-your-requirements-could-not-be-resolved-to-an-installable-set)

Comment: Error is quite clear, if a bit verbose. "aws/aws-sdk-php...require guzzlehttp/psr7 ^1.4.1...but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^2.5.0)." So your project's requirement for Guzzle 2.5 conflicts with the package's requirement for Guzzle 1.4. Seems like this aws-sdk-php package is quite outdated.

Comment: Why are there so many required packages? A lot of these would get installed as laravel dependencies on their own without needing to be explicitly declared in the root composer.json.

Comment: Actually, I think the problem is with your required version of `league/flysystem`. "I cleared out my composer.json and painfully added each package via "composer require" so i could get all the correct versions." Why? As IGP says, the typical Laravel app has a much smaller list of requirements. https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/10.x/composer.json

Comment: Do you , by any chance, have a way to go back to what the composer.json file looked like **before** you manually added each package to the require array? It probably seemed like a good idea at the time, but I assure you it had the opposite effect. When people speak about "dependency hell", this is what they mean. An enormous list of dependencies explicitly declared that conflict with each other's upgrades. I'm pretty sure the entire list of `symfony/*` packages will be required by laravel's `illuminate/foundation`.

Comment: @IGP thanks for the help. So I kindof inherited this project and learning laravel and composer by the firehose method.

I do have the original version of the composer.json. 
Would you suggest I just update the laravel/framework to 10 and do a composer update to start? Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @miken32 thanks for the feedback. I will try pruning the composer.json

Comment: When upgrading Laravel, just update the versions in your composer.json to match those in the Laravel app I linked above. The Laravel framework itself has its own that includes most of what you've included manually. https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/10.x/composer.json

Comment: @randy can you post the original version of that composer.json?

Comment: @IGP original version added

Comment: Oof. Unfortunately that is also pretty bad.

Comment: @IGP always fun inheriting projects :-)

Comment: I've added a little something below that might help you clean up your composer files

Comment: See https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues/2721 for more details about that incompatibility with `guzzlehttp/promises` - maybe you should downgrade that?

Answer (score 1):

This is not quite the answer to your question but it is a way for you to clean up your `composer.json` file (and it's too verbose to really put in a comment nicely formatted).

As the comments state, a lot of packages get installed as dependencies without needing to be explicitly declared. There is a way for you to know exactly which packages you can safely remove.

## Base `composer.json`

This is what the `require` segments look on a fresh Laravel 7 installation created with the command

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel:^7.0 blog
```

```json
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2.5|^8.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3.1|^7.0.1",
    "laravel/framework": "^7.29",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.5"
},
"require-dev": {
    "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.3",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5.8|^9.3.3"
},
```

## Extra baggage

Now, I'll add two packages that I know are already required, just to make an example

```json
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.2.5|^8.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
    "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3.1|^7.0.1",
    "laravel/framework": "^7.29",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
    "symfony/polyfill-php72": "^1.27", <---
    "symfony/polyfill-php80": "^1.27"  <---
},
"require-dev": {
    "facade/ignition": "^2.0",
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^4.3",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5.8|^9.3.3"
},
```

## What depends on X package?

Now how do you know (without prior knowledge) that `symfony/polifill-php80` and `symfony/polifill-php72` should not be there? A good way is using the command `composer why <package>`.

This command will tell why a package is installed. For example, for `laravel/tinker` this is the result:

```
$ composer why laravel/tinker

laravel/laravel - requires laravel/tinker (^2.5)
```

This tells you that `laravel/laravel` (the default name for your project (as stated in the `name` key of your `composer.json` is requiring `laravel/tinker`. Nothing else.

Now look at the result for `symfony/polyfill-php72` and `symfony/polyfill-php80`

```
$ composer why symfony/polyfill-php72
laravel/laravel           -       requires symfony/polyfill-php72 (^1.27)
symfony/polyfill-intl-idn v1.27.0 requires symfony/polyfill-php72 (^1.10)
```

this says that aside from it being in the `composer.json`'s require, another package installed in your vendor directory are also requiring it, meaning you can safely remove it from the `composer.json`

```
$ composer why symfony/polyfill-php80
laravel/laravel         -       requires symfony/polyfill-php80 (^1.27)
nesbot/carbon           2.68.1  requires symfony/polyfill-php80 (^1.16)
symfony/console         v5.4.24 requires symfony/polyfill-php80 (^1.16)
symfony/finder          v5.4.21 requires symfony/polyfill-php80 (^1.16)
symfony/http-foundation v5.4.25 requires symfony/polyfill-php80 (^1.16)
symfony/http-kernel     v5.4.25 requires symfony/polyfill-php80 (^1.16)
symfony/mime            v5.4.23 requires symfony/polyfill-php80 (^1.16)
symfony/process         v5.4.24 requires symfony/polyfill-php80 (^1.16)
symfony/routing         v5.4.25 requires symfony/polyfill-php80 (^1.16)
symfony/var-dumper      v5.4.25 requires symfony/polyfill-php80 (^1.16)
```

this says that aside from it being in the `composer.json`'s require, all these other packages installed in your vendor directory are also requiring it, meaning you can safely remove it from the `composer.json`

## Removing those packages

2 options:

- manually removing the line from the `composer.json` file and then running `composer update` (which will regenerate the `composer.lock` file from the modified `composer.json`
- running `composer remove <package>`

This is my output from trying to ***clean*** my `composer.json` file.

```
$ composer remove symfony/polyfill-php80
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update symfony/polyfill-php80
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Package fruitcake/laravel-cors is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package swiftmailer/swiftmailer is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/mailer instead.
Generating optimized autoload files
74 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
No security vulnerability advisories found
Removal failed, symfony/polyfill-php80 is still present, it may be required by another package. See `composer why symfony/polyfill-php80`.
```

The lines that are important here:

- ./composer.json has been updated (it removed the dependency from your require array)
- Nothing to modify in lock file (this didn't change your dependencies)
- Removal failed, symfony/polyfill-php80 is still present, it may be required by another package. See `composer why symfony/polyfill-php80`. (this is exactly what I was talking about: the dependency is already **required** by something else, so it being in your composer.json only clutters it for no reason.

---

... And basically you have the long task ahead of you of cleaning up your composer.json file from most of those packages.

Also whenever you're unsure about what a composer command will do, you can append `--dry-run` as an option. This will make the command just show the output without actually doing any changes.

Answer (score 0):

with alot of help from @IGP and @miken32
I been able to install the needed packages.

My final composer.json looks like

```
    "require": {
    "php": "^8.2",
    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.269",
    "elic-dev/laravel-site-protection": "^1.1",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
    "laravel/framework": "^10.10",
    "laravel/sanctum": "^3.2",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.8",
    "laravel/ui": "^4.2",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^6.4",
    "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^3.15",
    "spatie/laravel-permission": "^5.10",
    "spatie/laravel-sluggable": "^3.5"
},
```