# Mcrypt PHP extension required in Mac OS X El Capitan

Tags: php, macos, laravel, mcrypt

Getting error `Mcrypt PHP extension required.` with `Laravel` in Mac OS X El Capitan.

Already installed the mcrypt using `brew`.

```
brew install mcrypt
brew install homebrew/php/php55-mcrypt
sudo apachectl restart
```

**which php**

```
/usr/local/bin/php
```

**php --version**

```
PHP 5.5.30 (cli) (built: Oct  3 2015 23:48:03) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
```

**php --ini**

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/5.5
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/conf.d/ext-mcrypt.ini
```

Comment: http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-mcrypt-for-php-on-mac-osx-10-10-yosemite-for-a-development-server/

Comment: `$ brew install php55-mcrypt` see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26493762/yosemite-el-captian-php-gd-mcrypt-installation

Comment: @Kyslik I have installed php56 using this answer and it's working fine.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yu most rename original libphp:

```
sudo mv /usr/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so /usr/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so.origin
```

and link the new homebrew php lib installed

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.29/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so  /usr/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

and then restart apachectl

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

that works for me

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

http://phpbrew.github.io/phpbrew/

It lets you build any number of php versions, switch between them and set defaults. Add and remove extensions and more.

Good luck!